# how can i fix the .lower().capitalize() here?

Tags: python, discord.py

so,im trying to make a command that will fill a link with whatever will come after my command,

My code is

```
@client.command()
async def wikisearch(ctx, *args):
    await ctx.send.lower().capitalize()('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{}'.format('_'.join(args)))
```

so if is say $wikisearch Eiffel tower it the link will look like this "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_Tower"

before doing the ".lower().capitalize()" the thing was working perfectly, But I want to make it case insensitive

Comment: What do you mean by case insensitive?

Comment: What results do you get now?  Why do you need specific capitalization in a context that is, by definition, case insignificant?

Comment: first of all - url is NOT case sensitive, so you don't need to do that.

Comment: like,to ignore how its typed,if i type EIFFEL TOWER it will turn it into eiffel tower then Eiffel Tower or directly Eiffel tower

Comment: Also `lower()` and `capitalize()` are string class methods and not related to ctx

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/eiffel_tower <- click the link and check the url. URL are not case sensitive. eiffel_tower, or Eiffel_Tower all will end up at same place.

Comment: @Prune i get "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/[%50Eiffle', 'Tower']"

Comment: I highly doubt. For me it takes me to eiffel tower wikipage.

Comment: @Goion i need to search on other site,the wiki is just an example,on mine needs that to be capitalized

Comment: And you are not getting the point. You DON'T NEED TO change to casing. URLs are case insensitive. `await ctx.send('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{}'.format('_'.join(args)))` is only what you need.

Comment: Hey folks, there's no need to be rude here! Maybe OP doesn't really need clean capitalization to get a valid URL, but the question is still plain and simple: OP wants to know how to get clean capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lower(), capitalize() function on string types. Try this

```
ctx.send('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{}'.format('_'.join([arg.capitalize() for arg in args])))
```

You need to do [arg.lower().capitalize() for arg in args] because you are trying to make the first alphabet of each word in args capital. If this were not the case, you could simply do .lower() after the format()

Comment: i get this error "CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: can only join an iterable"

Comment: I don't see a point calling `.capitalize()` on the output of `.lower()` Lower here is doing nothing.

Comment: thanks for help,all i neede to do was to move the lower and capitalize thing where you put them and just remove the lower thing

Comment: @RainbowGuy bruh

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're using the command properly? I think `capitalize` and `lower` are intended to be string's methods.

Here:

```
'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{}'.format('_'.join(args))
```

You can

```
'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{}'.format('_'.join(args)).lower()
```

to convert all strings to lower case.

For a case insensitive match, its generally done by converting both sides of equation into a similar case.

```
# lhs    # rhs
angel    Angel
```

here, you will convert both the cases to a similar case,
preferably `capitalize` or `lower`

For example:

```py
'angel'.lower() == 'Angel'.lower()
```

Also, this command looks wrong in so many ways.
Please ensure you've read the documentation carefully.

```py
await ctx.send.lower().capitalize()('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{}'.format('_'.join(args)))
```